# How deal with taxonomy term parameter in multilingue site?

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a custom controller, who take the tid parameter :

```
/myroute/{tid}
```

The tid is upcast with the taxonomy Term so in my controller method I have:

```
public function index(TaxonomyTerm $tid)
```

In this function I can get the taxonomy entity.

But for call my controller, it's not SEO friendly... i have : /myroute/43 for example.

So I won't pass the term name, because you can have spécial caractere and it's not a good pratice in a multilingue site.

So for me the best way is to work with pathauto, generate the path for the taxonomy term so i can have :

/[term_category]/[term_name]

Now my question is how pass this to my controller.

I need to call my controller like that:

`<a href="myroute/{param_taxo}">`

So I am not sure how get the tid of the term with friendly url for SEO.

Any experience about that?

Comment: Normally path aliases are replaced before routing so that you have a valid internal path which matches a route. You can try this on two levels, either within the module pathauto by altering the alias, see pathauto.api.php or in a custom path processor on your own.

Comment: ok thank i ll take a look at pathauto.api.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must edit your route to be like this, `/myroute/{alias}`.

Then you can load the term in your controller like this:

```
public function index($alias) {
  // Find the term by path alias.
  $path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias($alias);
  if (preg_match('/taxonomy\/term\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches)) {
    $term = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($matches[1]);
  }
  if (isset($term) && $term instanceof TermInterface) {
    $term_id = $term->id();
  }
}
```

**NB:** The `path_alias.manager` service is added in Drupal 8.8.x, if you use an older version you must use the `path.alias_manager` service instead.

Comment: Ok, so no dynamic upcast, i can't really do like this for load the terms because pathauto use a clean path, so term with apostrophe will be replace with empty value. So i need to load by pathauto for get the term.

Comment: Try to look at my updated answer :)

Comment: @Kevin Sorry made a mistake in the regex. I have updated it now.

Comment: Interesting thank for this approch, {alias} parameter can contain / ? i'm not sure about that. but your first approch + your second i think that ll work

Comment: Have you tried to get a path that contains slashed with `getPathByAlias()`. I think it should work.

Comment: Ok thank, i ll try tomorow at office, and ll come back update your answer.

Comment: I tried to add a term with alias `test/test-alias`. This code `\Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias('/test/test-alias');` returns `/taxonomy/term/ID`. So it should work. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thank a lot for your time, have a good day

Comment: Thank this work like a charm

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it helped!